# Check if the current document in Visual Studio 2012 is a Code Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

I am looking for a way to have my extension check if the currently opened window in visual studio 2012 is one, where the user can write code (or any kind of text, really).

To check if the currently opened window has changed, I use

> _DTE.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated.

This gives me the `EnvDTE.Window` that received the focus.

When I look at the properties of that window while debugging, and I look at `EnvDTE.Window.Document.Type` and it's value is `"Text"`.

However, if I stop debugging and try to access the `Document.Type property`, it does not exist.

If I look for this property in the documentation of `EnvDTE.Window.Document`, its description says

> Infrastructure. Microsoft Internal Use Only.

So now I am looking for any advice on how I could check if the currently active window is one, where I can write code (or anything else), or some other kind of document (like the solution properties for example).

**Edit:**

I also tried checking `Window.Type` and `Window.Kind` of the active window, but they just tell me that it's a document, not making any differentiation between a resource file, an image file or an actual source file, which is what I'm trying to find out.

**Edit²:**

The reason why I want to check if the current document is one where I can write code in, is because I want my extension to store information about some of those documents and I want to modify the right-click context menu based on the information I have stored, if any.

Comment: Once you knew the answer, what would you do with it?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Sorry, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask me.

Comment: I think @Jason asks a valid question: what are you trying to do? What will the code do when your `IsTextDocument()` returns `false`? And what when `true`? What should happen when a text window is activated? Perhaps your approach is wrong for what you are trying to do, so the easiest solution could for example be to subscribe to another event, which we cannot suggest if you don't explain your end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a "real" answer, but you can follow status of VS GoTo command - it is available only for text editors:

```
bool isCodeWindow = IsCommandAvailable("Edit.GoTo");

private bool IsCommandAvailable(string commandName)
{
    EnvDTE80.Commands2 commands = dte.Commands as EnvDTE80.Commands2;
    if (commands == null)
        return false;

    EnvDTE.Command command = commands.Item(commandName, 0);
    if (command == null)
        return false;

    return command.IsAvailable;
}
```

Comment: The problem with those is, those properties have the same values, whether I open a resource file, an image file, or a source file. What I need is some way to determine if the document that is active right now is one where I really can write code in.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. You saved me a lot of trouble searching for some other workaround. It might not be the "best" way to do it, but it allows me to do what I need to and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the document is a 'TextDocument'

```
bool isCodeWindow = dte.CurrentDocument.Object() is EnvDTE.TextDocument;
```